# Layout de muitas colunas com datatable

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Estou com um problema com layout de datatable. Acabei criando um componente muito extenso (se não me engano, mais ou menos 25 colunas). Preciso deslocar uma dessas colunas (ano) de acordo com a barra de rolagem.

Movimentar com a barra eu já consegui, usando `position:fixed`. Contudo, gostaria de saber como poderia:

- Deixar o header com o mesmo height dos demais;
- Retirar a "sombra" que fica quando movimento do atributo (vide img 2)
- Como deixar as cores originais. Se eu tiro o `background-color`, ele fica transparente e inviabiliza a visualização.

Segue XHTML da coluna em questão:

```
<p:column width="187" headerText="Ano" style="background-color:#ddd; position:fixed; width:187;">
        <h:outputText value="#{f.ano}"/>
</p:column>
```

[image: altura do header]

[image: sombra ao mover coluna]

Answer (score 1):

Galera, consegui resolver o problema.

Segue código e print.

```
    <p:column width="187" style="background-color:inherit; position:fixed; width:187;">
         <f:facet name="header">        
            <div style="padding-bottom:25% !important; padding-top: 5%!important; background-color:inherit !important;">                
                <h:outputText value="Ano"/>
            </div>
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputText value="#{f.ano}"/>
    </p:column>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: muito bom, valeu